# Rationalized limit denominator, still undefined (divide by zero), how to solve?

Tags: limits, radicals

I am trying to solve:

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} - \sqrt{5x-1}}$$

My first step is to multiply by the conjugate to rationalize the denominator.

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} - \sqrt{5x-1}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}}{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}}$$

Which gives

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac
{(\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{3x-2}) \cdot (\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1})}
{({4x+1}) - ({5x-1})} $$

Simplifying denominator

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac
{(\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{3x-2}) \cdot (\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1})}
{2-x} $$

Substituting $2$ for $x$ in the denominator and it's zero

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac
{(\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{3x-2}) \cdot (\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1})}
{2-2} $$

Did I make a calculation error, if so where, and / or did I use the wrong approach, if so what's a working approach?

Comment: Try rationalizing the numerator also before substituting 2 for x

Comment: Ah, multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}}$?  Okay, doing it now, will report back.

Comment: You should have $(\sqrt {4x+1}+\sqrt {5x-1})$ in the numerator. You will see that $\sqrt {x+2}-\sqrt {3x-2}$ becomes $\sqrt 4 - \sqrt 4=0$ and to deal with this you should "rationalise" the numerator too.

Comment: Exactly!  below is the magic 1 that works when you have bad radicals in both top and bottom : $$\frac{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}} \times \frac{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}}$$

Comment: @MarkBennet Good spot, have edited to fix that sign error.

Comment: @ganeshie8 I didn't know that magic!  It looks like it will give me an ugly result compared to multiplying by the conjugate, with all those roots around.  Is that recommended over doing what I was planning to do i.e. multiply as I said in my comment four above this one?

Comment: nope, anything is fine... your method is good !

Comment: @topper It's the same multiplication in a different order.  Just rationalize what you started with and cancel what needs to be cancelled.  Don't bother trying to multiply out the rest.

Comment: I'm hitting a brick wall.  Numerator becomes $((\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{3x-2})\cdot(\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{5x-1}))\cdot(\sqrt{x+2}+{3x-2})$. Denominator becomes $(2-x)(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x-2})$.  This seems to be getting more and more complicated, and I seem to have more radicals, not less.  I think I can't see the forest for the trees.  Are my multiplications in this comment so far, sane?  I can understand multiplying my a conjugate to use the difference of squares rule to remove the roots, but here I just seem to be making things more complicated.  Despite all your help!

Comment: @Mike, I think you pre-empted my above comment.  I'm pretty lost at this point and mathlove's answer below, whilst technically amazing, leaves me wondering how I'd know to use that method next time I get a problem like this.

Comment: @ganeshie8 I just tried using your calculation. But I don't see how to cancel as Mike says. I have $$\frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} - \sqrt{5x-1}} \times \frac{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}} \times \frac{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}}$$ but no clue how to cancel, multiply, anything! :(

Comment: Looks very good :)  just look at first two fractions and use difference of squares. Save the last fraction till the end

Comment: $$\begin{align}\\ &\frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} - \sqrt{5x-1}} \times \frac{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}} \times \frac{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}} \\~\\ &= \frac{(x+2) - (3x-2)}{(4x+1)-(5x-1)} \times \frac{\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{5x-1}}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{3x-2}} \end{align}$$

Comment: Yes!  I didn't see that difference of squares lurking.  It's something I'm trying to train myself to spot, but obviously I'm not there yet.  So the first two terms equal 2 then I finish up with the last expression as per @mathlove's answer below.  So problem solved, how does it work from a site perspective as you both helped, but only mathlove provided an answer I can accept, yet I didn't understand mathlove's process, I understood yours better.  What's the etiquette?

Comment: Yep! Since all the bad denominators are gone, you can take the limit now :)

Comment: I think it is a good thing to accept the most helpful answer so that others know the problem is solved. Since you have only one answer you have no choice haha! I am new to stachexchange too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have
$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{3x-2}&=\frac{(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{3x-2})(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x-2})}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x-2}}\\&=\frac{-2(x-2)}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x-2}}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\sqrt{4x+1}-\sqrt{5x-1}&=\frac{(\sqrt{4x+1}-\sqrt{5x-1})(\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{5x-1})}{\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{5x-1}}\\&=\frac{-(x-2)}{\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{5x-1}}\end{align}$$

We have
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{3x+2}}{\sqrt{4x+1}-\sqrt{5x-1}}=\left(\frac{-2(x-2)}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x-2}}\right)\div\left(\frac{-(x-2)}{\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{5x-1}}\right)$$$$=\left(\frac{-2\color{red}{(x-2)}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x-2}}\right)\times\left(\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{5x-1}}{-\color{red}{(x-2)}}\right)=2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{5x-1}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x-2}}$$$$\to 2\cdot \frac{\sqrt 9+\sqrt 9}{\sqrt 4+\sqrt 4}=3\ (x\to 2).$$

Comment: I'm sure you're right, I understand the first two rows, but not the third.  I also don't understand the thought processes that would lead one to do the insane multiplications in the first two rows.  Happy if you want to enlighten me.  :)

Comment: @topper: Sure. I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: @topper: I thought I might be able to get $x-2$ by having the first two in my answer, which will enable us to get the limit by elinimating $x-2$.